# Binding to Properties of Nested CustomViews in a ViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Given I have the following setup (simplified version, removed logic to add to parent view and constraints etc).

```
public class TestViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
  string _text;
  public string Text
  {
    get => _text;
    set
    {
      _text = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => Text);
    }
  }
}


public class TestViewController : MvxViewController<TestViewModel>
  {
      CustomViewA customViewA;
      public TestViewController()
      {

      }

      public override void ViewDidLoad()
      {
          base.ViewDidLoad();

          var bindingSet = this.CreateBindingSet<TestViewController, TestViewModel>();

          bindingSet
              .Bind(customViewA)
              .For(v => v.Text)
              .To(vm => vm.Text);

          bindingSet.Apply();
      }
  }

public class CustomViewA : UIView
    {
        CustomViewB customViewB;

        public string Text
        {
            get => customViewB.Text;
            set => customViewB.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public class CustomViewB : UIView
    {
        UITextField textField;
        public string Text
        {
            get => textField.Text;
            set => textField.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Why is it that the bindings do not work? Only if I would make the UITextField in CustomViewB public and directly bind to it in the ViewController rather than the public property that directs to the Text property it seems to work. Like so:

```
bindingSet
              .Bind(customViewA.customViewB.textField)
              .For(v => v.Text)
              .To(vm => vm.Text);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the requirements you have.

Binding in one direction should work (view model-to-view), I have tested your code and when the `ViewModel` property changes, the change is propagated to `CustomViewA` and from there to `CusomViewB` and finally to the `UITextField`.

However, the problem is with the opposite direction (view-to-view model). When the user updates the text field, its `Text` property changes. However, there is **nothing notified** about this change.

Although the property `Text` points to the text field, it is not "bound" to it, so when `TextField`'s `Text` changes, the property itself doesn't know about it and neither does the MvvmCross binding.

In fact, MvvmCross binding in the control-to-view model direction is based on the ability to observe an event that tells the binding to check the new value of the bining source. This is already implemented for `UITextField`'s `Text`, and it hooks up the `EditingChanged` event (see [source code](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platform/iOS/Binding/Target/MvxUITextFieldTextTargetBinding.cs)).

You can still make custom bindings work in the view-to-view model direction by implementing them manually. This is [described in the documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/custom-data-binding).

Comment: Considering CustomViewB is used in CustomViewA and I want to bind it to the property in CustomViewA I would have to create 2 CustomBindings or should I just make the UITextField in CustomViewB public? Or what would you suggest is the cleanest solution in this case. It is basically a reusable component in another reusable component.